# Last ID inserted with c# and Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

How to have last ID inserted? I need new ID for child table.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with two OleDbCommand, one for INSERT statement, and one for SELECT @@IDENTITY statement. With second OleDbCommand, in one OleDbConnection, you can run first INSERT with ExecuteNonQuery and after SELECT @@IDENTITY with ExecuteScalar. You can. parse result to have new id.

```
public bool InserisciLibro(LibroCLS libro)
    {
        bool isSuccess = false;
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionstring))
        {
            con.Open();
            string SQL =@"INSERT INTO tblLibri (AutoreFK, Titolo,   Pagine,  EditoreFK, ISBN,   Notes) VALUES (@AutoreFK, @Titolo, @Pagine, @EditoreFK, @ISBN, @Notes);";
            int idnewlibro = 0;
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AutoreFK",libro.AutoreFK);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titolo", libro.Titolo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pagine", libro.Pagine);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EditoreFK", libro.EditoreFK);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", libro.ISBN);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", libro.Notes);
                int row = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //ora lancio il cmd per ottenere l'id autoincrementale ottenuto
                OleDbCommand cmdIdentity = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", con);                    
                idnewlibro =(int) cmdIdentity.ExecuteScalar();
                if (idnewlibro != 0)
                {
                    isSuccess = true;
                }                   
            }
        }
        return isSuccess;
    }
```

Comment: it's works. thanks!